# Targeted Display Mode using Henge Docks Vertical Dock

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, dock, target-display

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro with Retina Display and a Late 2012 21" iMac. I just purchased a [Henge Docks Vertical Dock](https://www.hengedocks.com/pages/vertical-macbook-pro-retina), to use at home, and the plan is to pop my MacBook Pro in and then use the iMac in Targeted Display Mode.

My question is, will this work? Thinking about it, I usually have to wake the MacBook Pro up for it to work in Targeted Display Mode, but as the lid is kept shut by the Vertical Dock, I am not sure it will work.

Has anyone had any experience with this set up?

If not, that's fine, I was planning to go and pick up a 27" monitor anyway (future plan is to run an external GPU for gaming).

Comment: Did you have any luck? I have a henge dock and am looking to do exactly the same! Thanks Liam

Answer (score 1):

Based on the specs you provided above....

> I have a 2012 MBPr and a late 2012 21" iMac....

This should work.  From Apple's website Use your [iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)

[image: iMacs Target Display]

Basically you need a [Thunderbolt cable](http://amzn.to/1VOyVyX) to connect from your TB port on your MBPr to your TB port on your iMac.

Once connected and booted, you just press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to toggle Targeted Display Mode on/off.

Comment: Hi @Allan (snap on the name!) i know that targeted display works, i use it all the time, what i am asking is, will i be able to start targeted display with the MBP lid shut. (as it will be in a docking station)

Comment: Having your MBPr in clamshell-closed mode with an external display should be no issue especially with the Henge as it really isn't a "dock" per se, but a really nice stand with the appropriate connections lined up.  You are still going from TB to TB, just now in clamshell closed mode.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834  Keep in mind, clamshell requires a strict procedure to enable.